# DHCP interface never transitions to configured state in systemd

Tags: networking, systemd

I have a server running CoreOS, and my main network interface that gets configured via DHCP gains a carrier and is routable, but never leaves the `configuring` state. This causes `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` to fail. Looking at the journal files for `systemd-networkd.service`, I see where the interface gets a carrier, but I see no error messages that would help me figure out why it's stuck in the `configuring` state. Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Below are some relevant details:

```
core@server ~ $ networkctl
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     configured
  2 enp0s25          ether              routable    configuring
  3 docker0          ether              no-carrier  configured

3 links listed.

core@server ~ $ networkctl status enp0s25
● 2: enp0s25
       Link File: /usr/lib64/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: /usr/lib64/systemd/network/zz-default.network
            Type: ether
           State: routable (configuring)
            Path: pci-0000:00:19.0
          Driver: e1000e
          Vendor: Intel Corporation
           Model: Ethernet Connection (3) I218-V
      HW Address: b8:ae:ed:76:f9:cd (Elitegroup Computer Systems Co., Ltd.)
         Address: 10.20.1.10
                  fe80::baae:edff:fe76:f9cd
         Gateway: 10.20.1.1 (ADI Engineering, Inc.)
             DNS: 8.8.8.8
                  8.8.4.4
  Search Domains: localdomain

core@server ~ $ journalctl -r -u systemd-networkd
-- Logs begin at Sat 2016-08-06 23:23:32 UTC, end at Sat 2016-10-08 17:29:00 UTC. --
Oct 08 17:03:41 nm-nuc systemd-networkd[1209]: enp0s25: DHCPv4 address 10.20.1.10/24 via 10.20.1.1
Oct 08 17:03:41 nm-nuc systemd-networkd[1209]: enp0s25: Gained carrier
Oct 08 17:03:41 nm-nuc systemd-networkd[1209]: docker0: Could not set bridge vlan: Operation not permitted
Oct 08 17:03:41 nm-nuc systemd-networkd[1209]: docker0: Failed to assign VLANs to bridge port: Operation not permitted
Oct 08 17:03:41 nm-nuc systemd-networkd[1209]: docker0: Could not append VLANs: Operation not permitted
Oct 08 17:03:41 nm-nuc systemd-networkd[1209]: docker0: IPv6 enabled for interface: Success
Oct 08 17:03:38 nm-nuc systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Oct 08 17:03:38 nm-nuc systemd-networkd[1209]: lo: Configured
Oct 08 17:03:38 nm-nuc systemd-networkd[1209]: enp0s25: IPv6 enabled for interface: Success
Oct 08 17:03:38 nm-nuc systemd-networkd[1209]: Enumeration completed
Oct 08 17:03:38 nm-nuc systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Oct 08 17:03:36 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped Network Service.
Oct 08 17:03:36 localhost systemd-networkd[350]: lo: Lost carrier
Oct 08 17:03:36 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping Network Service...
Oct 08 17:03:35 localhost systemd-networkd[350]: lo: Configured
Oct 08 17:03:35 localhost systemd-networkd[350]: eth0: IPv6 enabled for interface: Success
Oct 08 17:03:35 localhost systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Oct 08 17:03:35 localhost systemd-networkd[350]: Enumeration completed
Oct 08 17:03:35 localhost systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this, I have it too

Comment: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1028

Comment: Just in case anyone is coming here in 2019: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8686